# Bizzare Javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficult time understanding why 2 seemingly javascript blocks are
behaving unexpectedly:

```
   const fadeOutEffect = provider => {
    let fadeTarget = document.getElementById(provider);
    let fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
        console.log(fadeTarget.style.opacity);    //  prints out decremented value
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
      }
    }, 100);
  };

  const fadeInEffect = provider => {
    let fadeTarget = document.getElementById(provider);
    let fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 1) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity += 0.05;
        console.log(fadeTarget.style.opacity);    // prints out same value
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
      }
    }, 100);
  };
```

in one function I'm incrementing opacity of html element and in the other one I'm decrementing it. Yet first function does what I expect it to do which is decrementing the value, the second one though won't increment. Stays the same.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Properties of `.style` are all strings, so `"0.05" + 0.05` would become `"0.050.05"`, which is then interpreted as `0.05` again. You need to convert to a number explicitly.

Comment: That doesn't explain why value is changed in the first function and not in the second one. Without any need for `parseInt()`.

Comment: Value is changed in the first function. But the other remains same despite using the same way accessing the value.

Comment: When JS interpreter sees `-` it  converts both values to  number, since you can't subtract strings. But if one of the values is string, on addition it will convert both to strings. It is weird, yes, but it is the way it works, and you have to memorize at least most common ones, like this. You can read more, for example, here: https://dev.to/antonmelnyk/understanding-javascript-type-conversions-43n

Answer (score 0):

CSS properties are strings -

```js
function fadeOut (elem, ms)
{ const x = elem.style.opacity == ""
    ? 1
    : Number(elem.style.opacity)
  if (x == 0) return
  elem.style.opacity = String(x - 0.05) 
  setTimeout(fadeOut, ms, elem, ms)
}

const box1 =
  document.querySelector("#box1")
  
const box2 =
  document.querySelector("#box2")

fadeOut(box1, 50)
fadeOut(box2, 100)
```

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; opacity: 1; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="blue"></div>
<div id="box2" class="red"></div>
```

Perhaps a better way to write this would be to use a default argument -

```js
function fadeOut (elem, ms, opacity = 1)
{ if (opacity == 0) return
  elem.style.opacity = String(opacity) 
  setTimeout(fadeOut, ms, elem, ms, opacity - 0.05)
}

const box1 =
  document.querySelector("#box1")
  
const box2 =
  document.querySelector("#box2")

fadeOut(box1, 50)
fadeOut(box2, 100)
```

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; opacity: 1; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="blue"></div>
<div id="box2" class="red"></div>
```